# Angular 14 rendering optimization

Tags: angular, user-interface, optimization, angular-material, rendering

I have a page with a list of skills, and it shows like 400 skills, when it loads the page freezes for 2 seconds or so in my local. (surely on a less powerful machine it will take longer).

Is there a way to make all the elements load more smoothly? Or maybe some more optimal way to render them instead of the format it has now? Maybe I should render the elements only when the tab is clicked?

The elements do not have the on-push strategy since when they are clicked they change for example clicking on favorite makes the heart fill, should I change it and handle all the change detection by hand? Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

[image: page skills]

Comment: virtual scrolling or @rx-angular should help here [rxFor](https://www.rx-angular.io/docs/template/api/rx-for-directive)

Comment: Hey @Andrei thanks for the tip, with the rxFor works very well I didn't know about that library.

If you want put it as an answer and I market it, for this.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making components onPush doesn't help much here, as it does not affect the very first change detection cycle (only the following ones are improved).

but there is a set of utils `@rx-angular` that implements some angular utils with a focus on performance.

The one that should help in the question exaple is [rxFor](https://www.rx-angular.io/docs/template/api/rx-for-directive) directive witch should be used instead of usual ngFor one. It splits the rendering in several attempts automatically taking fps into account and there will be only several items (lets say 15) rendered in the first frame, while other items will be rendered in the following frames. The cool thing is that directive handles everything for you and no chunking/fps drops chekning logic is required from the user code side